# Openlayers 3 - Modifying a polygon after draw

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am trying to make a polygon editable after it is drawn with ol.interaction.Draw.
When I instantiate ol.interaction.Modify I get a "b.attachEvent is not a function" error. 
This is the code:

```
drawPolygon.on("drawend",function(p)
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        modifyPoligon = new ol.interaction.Modify({
            features: vectorSource.getFeatures()
        });
    },200);
}
```

I also use a timeout because in the drawend call the Feature is still not in the layer, is there a better way to get a callback after the feature is drawn and on the layer?

Comment: You don't need to instantiate `ol.interaction.Modify` inside `drawend`, just put it after your `ol.interaction.Draw`.

Comment: If I don't pass a feathers Collection, I get a "forEach" error. Can you provide a sample code?

Comment: I think the contrary is better, make a fiddle with your code and we debug it together.

Comment: @JonatasWalker https://jsfiddle.net/43qetjxa/

Comment: Don't forget to give some feedback!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if suits your case but here's a fiddle with a similar approach: https://jsfiddle.net/ko822xjw/

```
// Create a draw interaction and add it to the map:
drawInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({ source:vectorSource, type:"Polygon" });
map.addInteraction(drawInteraction);
// set listener on "drawend":
drawInteraction.on('drawend', function(e) {
  // get drawn feature:
  var feature = e.feature;
  // remove draw interaction:
  map.removeInteraction(drawInteraction);
  // Create a select interaction and add it to the map:
  selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select();
  map.addInteraction(selectInteraction);
  // select feature:
  selectInteraction.getFeatures().push(feature);
  // do something after drawing (e.g. saving):
  // ...
  // Create a modify interaction and add to the map:
  modifyInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({ features: selectInteraction.getFeatures() });
  map.addInteraction(modifyInteraction);
  // set listener on "modifyend":
  modifyInteraction.on('modifyend', function(evt) {
    // get features:
    var collection = evt.features;
    // There's only one feature, so get the first and only one:
    var featureClone = collection.item(0).clone();        
    // do something after modifying (e.g. saving):
    // ...
  });        
});
```

Comment: I noticed one strange thing: in the modifyInteraction, when deleting a vertex (by clicking on it), the geojson obtained with `var geojson = formatGeoJSON.writeFeature(featureClone);` is still identical to the previous version before deleting the vertex (see console). Is that a bug?

Comment: ...it's always one step behind: if you draw a polygon with 5 vertices, you get a GeoJSON with 6 coordinates (that's fine, the first one is equal to the last one). If you delete one vertex, the GeoJSON remains the same. If you delete another one, the GeoJSON contains 5 coordinates. *confused*

Comment: Features are not updated on vertex deletion in ol.interaction.Modify: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/4118

Answer (score 0):

It could be as simple as:

```
var
    features = new ol.Collection(),
    modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
        features: features
    }),
    vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: features
    }),
    vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource
    }),
    map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'})
            }),
            vectorLayer
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 2
        })
    }),
    drawPolygon = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        features: features,
        type: 'Polygon'
    })
;
map.addInteraction(modify);
map.addInteraction(drawPolygon);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/r2g1atty/